Fourier multiplier definition (tempered distributions)
Definition (Fourier multiplier) Let $T$ a tempered distribution. $T$ is called a Fourier multiplier on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if the convolution $(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(T))*\varphi\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $\varphi$ Schwartz function and if $\sup_{\left\|\varphi\right\|_{p}}\left\|(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(T))*\varphi\right\|_p$ is finite.
Reference: J. Bergh, and J. Löfström, Interpolation Spaces: An Introduction (Springer Berlin Heidelberg, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1976).
Question. What is the meaning that $(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(T))*\varphi\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Is that $(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(T))*\varphi=\int g\varphi$ for some $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
Thanks.

First of all, by definition $\mathcal F^{-1}(T)$ is again a tempered distribution. The convolution of a tempered distribution with a Schwartz function is defined to be the distribution applied to the translated function, as follows:
$$((\mathcal F^{-1}(T)) * \varphi)(x) := (\mathcal F^{-1}(T))(\varphi(x - \cdot)).$$
Note that the right hand side is a (real or complex) number.
Therefore the convolution of a tempered distribution with a Schwartz function is always a function $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb C$. And for this function, you know how to check if it is in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$. Of course, you may also check this by the "distributional formulation": Check that
$$\int (\mathcal F^{-1}(T))(\varphi(x- \cdot)) \psi(x)dx = \int g(x) \psi(x) dx$$
for some function $g \in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and all $\psi \in \mathscr S(\mathbb R^n)$, but this is not really helpful as you can see because $(\mathbb F^{-1}(T))(\varphi(x- \cdot))$ is already a function defined pointwisely so this approach amounts to once again showing "by first principles" that $(\mathcal F^{-1}(T))(\varphi(x-\cdot))$ is in $L^p$.

Oh, I see. If $T$ is a tempered distribution and $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function, then their convolution is a function defined by $x\mapsto (T*\varphi)(x)= T(\varphi(x-\cdot))$. Thank you.
